# Sequelize range types and resolvers

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a Parties resolver and im willing to get all the parties that are in a range of dates.

(parties have a property "partyDate")

```
parties(root, args){
  return Parties.findAll(
     {
       where: args,
     }
  );
}
```

According to [Sequelize Range Types Docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/?highlight=dates#range-types) this is the way to create a range..

```
Timeline.create({ range: [myDateObject1, myDateObject2] });
```

But how do i retrieve a collection of parties where partyDate (ie. 03/12/2015) is between myDateObject1 and myDateObject2

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i found the solution:

In the where statement you must query a range `$lt-$gt` of date.

```
where...

  partyDate: {
    $lt: myDateObject1,
    $gt: myDateObject2
  }
```